# V-model for select component

Tags: vuejs2

In  Vue we can bind data on two way in the select component like below:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

Our Vue code is:

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Here `v-model` property works for the value of the option.

Is there any method for the same thing to the text property of the option.

In other words, is there any method works with `One`,`Two` and `Three` values.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but there is [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html): https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/m2vmpr4x/

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. You can not bind the text within option tags. It only works as `<option>text</option>` so the text must be b/n your option tags. So, you code is correct. Also there is something that looks like this `✓` in stackoverflow. You use it to accept an answer when someone tries to help you here. Please use it.